# c# WCF Creating/calling a service from another service

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

So from my client application I create a proxy to "Service1" on its own host. Then I want Service1 to create multiple instances of "Service2" on a different host. The instances of Service2 should then relay data back to Service1 which will do some operations and then service1 will relay data back to the client application.

From a design point of view I am trying to figure out how Service1 should instantiate the instances of service2. service2 has its own client class that can instantiate the proxy so I thought i could just reference service2 clients class in service1 and just create instances, but this just creates null objects.

At this point i thought i needed to create a new proxy of service2 in service1. so in service1 i added a service reference to service2. This gave me an error that it could not find an endpoint and contract in the servicemodel configuration section.

So maybe these approaches are just incorrect and i am thinking that my client application should instantiate service1 and service2 instances and then they communicate through proxies to each other, but then wouldnt i have the same endpoint and contract issue like the one above?

Thanks for any guidance

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around i figured out the issue, since i was creating service2 in service1 i needed to add the serviceModel to the host where service1 resided, this cleared up the end point and contract error